# How to implement a trait

Tags: rust, traits

I am trying to implement a new trait called `AppendBar` for `String`. Its only function is `append_bar`.

From my understanding, `self` should be an instance of a String.

```rust
trait AppendBar {
    fn append_bar(self) -> Self;
}

impl AppendBar for String {
    fn append_bar(self) -> Self{
        self.clone().push_str("Bar")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = String::from("Foo");
    let s = s.append_bar();
    println!("s: {}", s);  // "s: FooBar"
}
```

This is obviously not the case, because I receive the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> exercises/traits/traits1.rs:18:9
   |
17 |     fn append_bar(self) -> Self{
   |                            ---- expected `std::string::String` because of return type
18 |         self.clone().push_str("Bar")
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found `()`
```

Can anyone help me understand my misconception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@loganfsmyth's answer explains why you get this error message. There are three ways to solve it depending on your expectations for `append_bar`:

## Take ownership

If you expect `append_bar` to return the modified string and don't want the caller to be able to use the input string afterwards:

```
impl AppendBar for String {
    fn append_bar (mut self) -> Self {
        self.push_str ("Bar");
        self
    }
}
let s1 = String::from ("Foo");
let s2 = s1.append_bar();
// println!("s1: {}", s1);    // Error: s1 is no longer usable at this point
println!("s2: {}", s2);    // Prints "FooBar"
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d5101e4cc4d21d7aab62d08fcc45cbf2)

(This is the same solution as @loganfsmyth's answer).

## Borrow and clone

If you expect `append_bar` to return the modified string and want the caller to be able to keep using the original input string afterwards:

```
impl AppendBar for String {
    fn append_bar (&self) -> Self {
        let mut s = self.clone();
        s.push_str ("Bar");
        s
    }
}
let s1 = String::from ("Foo");
let s2 = s1.append_bar();
println!("s1: {}", s1);    // Prints "Foo"
println!("s2: {}", s2);    // Prints "FooBar"
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2abe7db2ffa6329f5673f7775c36034d)

## Mutate in place

If you expect `append_bar` to replace the input with the modified string:

```
impl AppendBar for String {
    fn append_bar (&mut self) {
        self.push_str ("Bar");
    }
}
let mut s1 = String::from ("Foo");
s1.append_bar();
println!("s1: {}", s1);    // Prints "FooBar"
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=39d379bafa5de0f4d357c6f68e5ab2ab)

Answer (score 8):

```
17 |     fn append_bar(self) -> Self{
   |                            ---- expected `std::string::String` because of return type
18 |         self.clone().push_str("Bar")
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found `()`
```

is saying that it expected `append_bar` to return a `String`, but `self.clone().push_str("Bar")` evaluates to a type of [`()`, the unit type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.unit.html).  The compiler error is correct, because the [`push_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.push_str) function's type is `fn push_str(&mut self, string: &str)`, note that it has no return type and instead mutates its `Self` argument.

Instead, you need to push into the string and then return the string, e.g.

```
impl AppendBar for String {
    fn append_bar(mut self) -> Self{
        self.push_str("Bar");
        self
    }
}
```

I've also remove the `.clone()` because it was not necessary. `append_bar` already accepts `self` and thus takes ownership of the string value, so you can push into it and return it without needing to clone it.